# Duplicate result in Oracle / PLSQL: MINUS Operator?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

**TABLE 1**

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, ... FROM A
MINUS
SELECT col_1, col_2, ... FROM B
```

**TABLE 2**

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, ... FROM B
MINUS
SELECT col_1, col_2, ... FROM A
```

Why some records in Table 1 appears the same as in Table 2 (DUPLICATE)??
When duplicate shouldn't happen in a MINUS Operator

**TABLE 1**

```
ID  FRUIT    SEED   COLOUR
1   PAPAYA   YES    ORANGE
2   APPLE    YES    RED
```

**TABLE 2**

```
ID  FRUIT    SEED   COLOUR
1   MANGO    YES    YELLOW
2   APPLE    YES    RED
```

Table 1 Record 2 = Table 2 Record 2
Why?

Comment: share sample data

Comment: Create a reproducer here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18

Comment: I think the ID of apple is different in your tables.

Comment: Show us table A and table B sample data, that gives the specified result.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a real duplicate. The ID of the apple record is different in your tables.

Comment: Try to use the trim Oracle function on your columns. Perhaps you have a whitespace in your values.

Answer (score 0):

The records are not really the same; the values just look the same.  This is usually caused by leading or trailing spaces on strings, but there are many other reasons:

- Hidden characters in strings.
- "Look-alike" characters in different character sets (think lower case L and the number one).
- Types where the full value is not typically displayed, such as `date` data types.

You would need to investigate your data to see what the actual problem is.  One way to begin is to delimit the values in the tables to see if there are spaces:

```
select id, '"' || fruit || '"', . . .
from table1;
```